# QML import error

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I wanted to create a new QML type from C++ but I encountered a problem in the process, which I couldn't resolve. I have a class in C++ - `"Mytype"` - which has been registered with the QML Type System via `qmlregistertype` function.

So far so good. The class was correctly registered and the application run fine on desktop environments, everything worked fine. However, when I built and deployed the application to an Android device, I received the following error:

> **Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Mytype**

What does this error talk about? What could be the reason for this error? How can I fix it? Please, help me. Here follows a simplified code example:

> c++:

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
    #include "mytype.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Mytype>("mytype", 1, 0, "Mytype");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

> qml:

```
import mytype 1.0;
...
Mytype {
    id: my_type;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You registered the type as `Mytest`, but try to use it as `Mytype`. Your import is also wrong. Replace `Mytype` with `Mytest` in your QML and it should work.